# How to send data from View to Controller without ajax?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Right now, I am calling controller method by using:

```
<a class="k-button" href="@Url.Action("ExportData", "Home")">ExportData</a>
```

Works fine but also I need to send two strings in Controller, get DateTime from them and use them to get data from list.
It's is very simple by using Ajax, but how can I do it in another way?
The reason why I can't use ajax is because Controller method ExportData returns:

```
return File(csv, "text/csv", fileName);
```

For some reason I can't download anything by using ajax.
Also by using Url.Action I can send one parameter but no more.

**EDIT:**
Also I need to get those strings from:

```
<input class="k-in" style="width: 150px; padding: 0; font-size: 0.9em;" type="text" id="DateFrom" name="DateFrom"/>
<input class="k-in" style="width: 150px; padding: 0; font-size: 0.9em;" type="text" id="DateTo" name="DateTo" />
```

Comment: Use the Html.ActionLink() helper to create the link.  It accepts a parameter for additional route values (basically just a query string with keys/values) which your ActionResult in your controller can accept.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get how it should look =(

Comment: Did you send input control value too with Url.Action ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass route values like this in Action method

```
  <a class="k-button" href="@Url.Action("ExportData", "Home",new {p1="sa",p2="as"})">ExportData</a>
```

And fetch this data back in you ExportData method like this

```
public ActionResult ExportData(string p1,string p2)
{
   ...
}
```

As per you requirement, make one javascript function like this

```
 function test(){
   var url=@Url.Action("ExportData", "Home");
   var p1="12";//now you can set this value by javascript 
   var p2="123";
   window.location.href = url + "?p1=" + p1 + "&p2=" + p2;//this will call you action method and pass you parameter.
 }
```

Now you can call this function on click of button or anchor tag which you want.

Comment: Hm...is it possible to somehow use javascript functions (which are getting needed string) instead of hardcoding values? (sa,as)

Comment: No As @Url.Action method execute at server side you can not set route values by javascript. for that you need to create one form and submit that form on button click

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function YourMethod(data) 
    {            
        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ExportData", "Home")?id=" + data;                   
    }
```

You can append any number of params this way.